# Three.js - Can't retrieve objects from function objects

Tags: javascript, function, three.js

Here's my function.

```
function Planet(radius, c) {

    var sphere = new THREE.Mesh(
        new THREE.SphereGeometry(radius, 64, 64),
        new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({ color: c })
    );

}
```

I then create an object out of the function.

```
var planet = new Planet(1, 0xffffff);
```

Finally I attempt to add the planet object's sphere mesh to the three.js scene.

```
scene.add(planet.sphere);
```

I get no errors in the Chrome JavaScript console, but the sphere isn't showing up. If I create a sphere mesh from outside the Planet function and add it to the scene, it works. It wouldn't really make sense to have everything outside functions in the long run, though. I'm eventually going to have to create multiple arrays to store a single planet.

Comment: This was just the first hit from google: javascript scope. Not an endorsement.  http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2009/08/01/what-you-need-to-know-about-javascript-scope/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
function Planet(radius, c) {

    this.sphere = new THREE.Mesh(
        new THREE.SphereGeometry(radius, 64, 64),
        new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({ color: c })
    );

}

var planet = new Planet(1, 0xffffff );
scene.add(planet.sphere);
```

or

```
function Planet(radius, c) {

    return new THREE.Mesh(
        new THREE.SphereGeometry(radius, 64, 64),
        new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({ color: c })
    );

}

var planet = new Planet(1, 0xffffff);
scene.add(planet);
```